# Maintenance mode in public page not in admin page [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel-5

Now i'm working on laravel web project, there is the feature on admin page to set web as maintenance mode, but this maintenance just stop proceed the request which come in public page, I tried to make middleware so all route or controller which handle public page will stop if setting is set on maintenance mode. (settings are saved in database that has value 'online' or 'maintenance')

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null){
    // retrieve setting from database and turn into key value array
    if($site_settings['status'] == 'maintenance'){
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

what my approach is incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you registered your middleware in `Kernel.php`?

You need to add it to `app/Http/Kernel.php`, under the Global middleware comment:

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddlewareClass::class, // add it here
];
```

And create a middleware class in `app/Http/Middleware` with a public function `handle`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class YourMiddlewareClass
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null){
        if ( $site_settings['status'] == 'maintenance' && !$request->is('admin/*') ){
            return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
        }
       
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This will force error 500 on anything that doesn't start with `admin/` in the URL.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer with additional code to help.

Comment: hmm i could remove `!$request->is('admin/*')` from global and just add middleware on public page route, thanks btw..

Comment: yep, either way would work. Using as global middleware could save you hassle of updating routes file, but it's your preference.